# Xamarin Android Galaxy Watch 4 get list of audio tracks added with the Galaxy Wearable app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin to develop a watch (Wear OS) app that needs to be able to retrieve the audio tracks added via the Galaxy Wearable phone app.  I can see these files using ADB and myWear file explorer in the folder /sdcard/music/GalaxyWearable of my watch but I cannot get these files from my Xamarin app.
IE:
`Directory.GetFiles("/sdcard/music/GalaxyWearable");`
returns 0 files.

I am new to Android development and I don't understand why this is happening.

Please help!

I've tried adding the following permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENT" />
```

This did not help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Watch OS, but in Android 12 and up, you don't access media files that way. File access has been restricted, to improve security. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: use [Android Media](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary) APIs to access the media library

Comment: Thanks ToolMakerSteve! figured it out.  I was missing `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />`  This permission is required to access audio files created by other applications.